# Nested inline-flex containers overlap parent elements in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a component that is building sections in menus. This component uses flexbox in a few locations. My approach seems to be working for most browsers, but IE10/11 run into issues. I've tried looking through [some common flexbox issues in IE](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs), but I can't seem to narrow down my issue to the specific problem. The snippet below is a close representation of the problem.

Essentially I want the purple box to fully contain the green box. I'm guessing the issue is related the min-width I've supplied to the `menu-section` rule, but I can't seem to find a good solution to the nested flex container overflowing the section.

```css
.menu-wrapper {
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em;
}

.menu-section {
  outline: 3px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.menu-items-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-flex;
 display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
 flex-flow: wrap;
  /* Using this writing mode hack to get columns to respect wrapped element size in Chrome/FF */
 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
 -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.menu-items-wrapper > * {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  -ms-writing-mode: lr-tb;
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}

.menu-item {
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <div class="menu-section">
    <div class="menu-items-wrapper">
      <a class="menu-item">One</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Two</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Three</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Four</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Five</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Six</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Seven</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Eight</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Nine</a>
      <a class="menu-item">Ten</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a screenshot of what this looks like in IE11:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `inline-flex`? Does `.menu-wrapper` shares its container with some other elements?

Comment: In my specific case yes.

Comment: Great, can you show the HTML context then, and the specific CSS for the context?

Comment: In the actual larger case this example lives in, I can variably add the additional section. I can have the example above exist in a standalone state. I was hoping to simply have the inline-flex element work on it's own if possible because I'm seeing the overflow issue explained above when this code exists on its own. I can probably recreate the larger full example, but that just seemed to conflate the issue described above with other minor, unrelated issues I still need to clean up.